# Promise doesn't get resolved in route before controller got instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the needed data directly in the route, before the controller which is going to render the view got instantiated.

For instance:

```
angular.module( 'mean.characters', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'] );

angular.module( 'mean.characters' ).factory('CharactersInfoFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/character/:characterId',
    { characterId: '@characterId' });
}]);

angular.module( 'mean.characters' ).config(['$stateProvider',
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('bio', {
          url: '/:characterName/bio',
          templateUrl: 'characters/views/bio.html',
          resolve: {
                CharactersInfoFactory: 'CharactersInfoFactory',
                character: function(CharactersInfoFactory, $stateParams) {
                    var characterName = $stateParams.characterName;
                    return CharactersInfoFactory.get({characterId: characterName}).$promise;
                }
          },
          controller: 'CharactersBioController'
        });
  }
]);

angular.module( 'mean.characters' ).controller('CharactersBioController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'character',
  function($scope, Global, character) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.package = {
      name: 'characters'
    };

    $scope.character = character;

    console.log($scope.character);
  }

]);
```

The data is well retrieved, but the promise is not resolved before the view got rendered.

The console.log prints the info properly in console, but i also get the next error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: characterProvider <- character
```

Besides, the view doesn't print the info ({{ character.name }} for example). It just shows the string "{{ character.name }}" instead of the name itself.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a JSFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Uhm, i think i don't know how to reproduce the call to the db in the factory in a JSFiddle. I've barely used JSFiddle...

Comment: It would just 404, or you could not make the call and return a `$q.defer()` -- but really what I'm trying to get at is, how different is the code in this question from what you're actually running?

Comment: The code has been copied and pasted without any change. The only different between my code and the pasted one here is that the original one is splitted in several files (routes.js, charactersBio.js, charactersInfoFactory.js...). But i don't think that would be the problem as there is not any error related to it...

Comment: So you're using `$resource` without including `ngResource` as a module dependency?

Comment: Yep, that seems. I already add it and there is not any change in the behavior. I get the same errors. It's like the $promise part was not executed, it is completely ignored.

Comment: So, debug: if you change character to be a function that just returns 'foo' with no dependencies, what happens? Then what if you do q.defer and a setTimeout? Try listening `on` `$stateChangeError` and seeing if that is being fired.